# Convert 2 Azure pipelines into one pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

i have 2 azure pipelines for Devops/MLops

1. first pipeline to train and register model
2. second pipeline to deploy the model to azure Container Instance

i want to convert the second pipeline into a stage in the first pipeline but i have some variables that depends on the first pipeline

here is m first pipeline :

```
    resources:
  containers:
  - container: mlops
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mlops/python:latest

pr: none
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - diabetes_regression/
    - ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline.py
    - ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline_with_r.py
    - ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline_with_r_on_dbricks.py

variables:
- template: diabetes_regression-variables-template.yml
- group: devopsforai-aml-vg

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: 'Model_CI'
  displayName: 'Model CI'
  jobs:
  - job: "Model_CI_Pipeline"
    displayName: "Model CI Pipeline"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - template: code-quality-template.yml
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          export SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)
          # Invoke the Python building and publishing a training pipeline
          python -m ml_service.pipelines.diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline
      displayName: 'Publish Azure Machine Learning Pipeline'

- stage: 'Trigger_AML_Pipeline'
  displayName: 'Train and evaluate model'
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
    BUILD_URI: '$(SYSTEM.COLLECTIONURI)$(SYSTEM.TEAMPROJECT)/_build/results?buildId=$(BUILD.BUILDID)'
  jobs:
  - job: "Get_Pipeline_ID"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(coalesce(variables['auto-trigger-training'], 'true'), 'true'))
    displayName: "Get Pipeline ID for execution"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          export SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)
          python -m ml_service.pipelines.run_train_pipeline --output_pipeline_id_file "pipeline_id.txt" --skip_train_execution
          # Set AMLPIPELINEID variable for next AML Pipeline task in next job
          AMLPIPELINEID="$(cat pipeline_id.txt)"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AMLPIPELINEID;isOutput=true]$AMLPIPELINEID"
      name: 'getpipelineid'
      displayName: 'Get Pipeline ID'
  - job: "Run_ML_Pipeline"
    dependsOn: "Get_Pipeline_ID"
    displayName: "Trigger ML Training Pipeline"
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool: server
    variables:
      AMLPIPELINE_ID: $[ dependencies.Get_Pipeline_ID.outputs['getpipelineid.AMLPIPELINEID'] ]
    steps:
    - task: ms-air-aiagility.vss-services-azureml.azureml-restApi-task.MLPublishedPipelineRestAPITask@0
      displayName: 'Invoke ML pipeline'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        PipelineId: '$(AMLPIPELINE_ID)'
        ExperimentName: '$(EXPERIMENT_NAME)'
        PipelineParameters: '"ParameterAssignments": {"model_name": "$(MODEL_NAME)"}, "tags": {"BuildId": "$(Build.BuildId)", "BuildUri": "$(BUILD_URI)"}, "StepTags": {"BuildId": "$(Build.BuildId)", "BuildUri": "$(BUILD_URI)"}'
  - job: "Training_Run_Report"
    dependsOn: "Run_ML_Pipeline"
    condition: always()
    displayName: "Publish artifact if new model was registered"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - template: diabetes_regression-publish-model-artifact-template.yml
```

my second pipeline (Deploy to Aci):

```
# Continuous Integration (CI) pipeline that orchestrates the deployment of the diabetes_regression model.

# Runtime parameters to select artifacts
parameters:
- name : artifactBuildId
  displayName: Model Train CI Build ID. Default is 'latest'.
  type: string
  default: latest

pr: none

# Trigger this pipeline on model-train pipeline completion
trigger: none
resources:
  containers:
  - container: mlops
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mlops/python:latest
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: model-train-ci
    source: Model-Train-Register-CI # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master

variables:
- template: diabetes_regression-variables-template.yml
- group: devopsforai-aml-vg

stages:
- stage: 'Deploy_ACI'
  displayName: 'Deploy to ACI'
  condition: variables['ACI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME']
  jobs:
  - job: "Deploy_ACI"
    displayName: "Deploy to ACI"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - download: none
    - template: diabetes_regression-get-model-id-artifact-template.yml
      parameters:
        projectId: '$(resources.pipeline.model-train-ci.projectID)'
        pipelineId: '$(resources.pipeline.model-train-ci.pipelineID)'
        artifactBuildId: ${{ parameters.artifactBuildId }}
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      displayName: 'Install AzureML CLI'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: 'az extension add --source https://azurecliext.blob.core.windows.net/release/azure_cli_ml-1.27.0-py3-none-any.whl --yes'
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      displayName: "Deploy to ACI (CLI)"
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(SOURCES_DIR_TRAIN)/scoring
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          
          az ml model deploy --name $(ACI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME) --model '$(MODEL_NAME):$(get_model.MODEL_VERSION)' \
          --ic inference_config.yml \
          --dc deployment_config_aci.yml \
          -g $(RESOURCE_GROUP) --workspace-name $(WORKSPACE_NAME) \
          --overwrite -v
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      displayName: 'Smoke test'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          export SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)
          python -m ml_service.util.smoke_test_scoring_service --type ACI --service "$(ACI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME)"
```

the pipeline that i don't know how to get are :

```
  parameters:
    projectId: '$(resources.pipeline.model-train-ci.projectID)'
    pipelineId: '$(resources.pipeline.model-train-ci.pipelineID)'
```

because they get the project and pipeline id from model-train-ci pipeline

i looked for how to get the ids from current running pipeline and didn't get anything

i tried to use the variable $AMLPIPELINEID from the job Get_pipline_ID but it's empty

here is what i tried and what the current file looks like  :

```
    # Continuous Integration (CI) pipeline that orchestrates the training, evaluation, and registration of the diabetes_regression model.
parameters:
- name : artifactBuildId
  displayName: Model Train CI Build ID. Default is 'latest'.
  type: string
  default: latest

resources:
  containers:
  - container: mlops
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mlops/python:latest

pr: none
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - diabetes_regression/
    - ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline.py
    - ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline_with_r.py
    - ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline_with_r_on_dbricks.py

variables:
- template: diabetes_regression-variables-template.yml
- group: devopsforai-aml-vg

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: 'Model_CI'
  displayName: 'Model CI'
  jobs:
  - job: "Model_CI_Pipeline"
    displayName: "Model CI Pipeline"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - template: code-quality-template.yml
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          export SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)
          # Invoke the Python building and publishing a training pipeline
          python -m ml_service.pipelines.diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline
      displayName: 'Publish Azure Machine Learning Pipeline'

- stage: 'Trigger_AML_Pipeline'
  displayName: 'Train and evaluate model'
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
    BUILD_URI: '$(SYSTEM.COLLECTIONURI)$(SYSTEM.TEAMPROJECT)/_build/results?buildId=$(BUILD.BUILDID)'
  jobs:
  - job: "Get_Pipeline_ID"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(coalesce(variables['auto-trigger-training'], 'true'), 'true'))
    displayName: "Get Pipeline ID for execution"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          export SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)
          python -m ml_service.pipelines.run_train_pipeline --output_pipeline_id_file "pipeline_id.txt" --skip_train_execution
          # Set AMLPIPELINEID variable for next AML Pipeline task in next job
          AMLPIPELINEID="$(cat pipeline_id.txt)"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AMLPIPELINEID;isOutput=true]$AMLPIPELINEID"
      name: 'getpipelineid'
      displayName: 'Get Pipeline ID'
  - job: "Run_ML_Pipeline"
    dependsOn: "Get_Pipeline_ID"
    displayName: "Trigger ML Training Pipeline"
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool: server
    variables:
      AMLPIPELINE_ID: $[ dependencies.Get_Pipeline_ID.outputs['getpipelineid.AMLPIPELINEID'] ]
    steps:
    - task: ms-air-aiagility.vss-services-azureml.azureml-restApi-task.MLPublishedPipelineRestAPITask@0
      displayName: 'Invoke ML pipeline'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        PipelineId: '$(AMLPIPELINE_ID)'
        ExperimentName: '$(EXPERIMENT_NAME)'
        PipelineParameters: '"ParameterAssignments": {"model_name": "$(MODEL_NAME)"}, "tags": {"BuildId": "$(Build.BuildId)", "BuildUri": "$(BUILD_URI)"}, "StepTags": {"BuildId": "$(Build.BuildId)", "BuildUri": "$(BUILD_URI)"}'
  - job: "Training_Run_Report"
    dependsOn: "Run_ML_Pipeline"
    condition: always()
    displayName: "Publish artifact if new model was registered"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    steps:
    - template: diabetes_regression-publish-model-artifact-template.yml
- stage: 'Deploy_ACI'
  displayName: 'Deploy to ACI'
  condition: variables['ACI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME']
  jobs:
  - job: "Deploy_ACI"
    displayName: "Deploy to ACI"
    container: mlops
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    variables:
      AMLPIPELINE_ID: $[ dependencies.Get_Pipeline_ID.outputs['getpipelineid.AMLPIPELINEID'] ]
    steps:
    - download: none
    - template: diabetes_regression-get-model-id-artifact-template.yml
      parameters:
        projectId: '$(AMLPIPELINE_ID)'
        pipelineId: '$(AMLPIPELINE_ID)'
        artifactBuildId: ${{ parameters.artifactBuildId }}
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      displayName: 'Install AzureML CLI'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: 'az extension add --source https://azurecliext.blob.core.windows.net/release/azure_cli_ml-1.27.0-py3-none-any.whl --yes'
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      displayName: "Deploy to ACI (CLI)"
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(SOURCES_DIR_TRAIN)/scoring
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          
          az ml model deploy --name $(ACI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME) --model '$(MODEL_NAME):$(get_model.MODEL_VERSION)' \
          --ic inference_config.yml \
          --dc deployment_config_aci.yml \
          -g $(RESOURCE_GROUP) --workspace-name $(WORKSPACE_NAME) \
          --overwrite -v
    - task: AzureCLI@1
      displayName: 'Smoke test'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          export SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(az account show --query id -o tsv)
          python -m ml_service.util.smoke_test_scoring_service --type ACI --service "$(ACI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME)"
```

in the 2nd pipeline resources there was  :

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: model-train-ci
    source: Model-Train-Register-CI
```

which i can't define now because i have 1 pipeline and it can't reference it self

instead of :

```
'$(resources.pipeline.model-train-ci.pipelineID)'
```

i need to change model-train-ci (which is the 1st pipeline name) to the current merged pipeline

should look somehitng like this but i didn't find anything on the internet :

```
 parameters:
projectId: '$(<current-projectID>)'
pipelineId: '$(<current-pipelineID)'
```

im really stuck here and new to this if someone could guide me to the right direction

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: no it doesn't i had to use 2 pipelines , couldn't get the ids

Answer (score 0):

> i want to convert the second pipeline into a stage in the first pipeline but i have some variables that depends on the first pipeline

Personally, what you're doing so far is in the right direction：

> **change model-train-ci (which is the 1st pipeline name) to the current merged pipeline**

The pipeline resource variables `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.projectID` is available to all jobs in the form of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops).

So, it should be equivalent to `Build.TriggeredBy.ProjectID` before you merge.

But after we merge the pipelines, there is no resource pipeline, only the current pipeline. To get the `projectID` of current pipeline, you could try to use the `System.TeamProjectId`.

You could check the document [System variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) for some more details.